# Can you give me a deeper background regarding Microsoft's "Coded UI?"

Tags: coded-ui-tests

"My team lead just gave me a task to study about Coded UI, then create a program afterwards. He told me to focus on the 'code' rather than 'record'. Honestly, I don't have an idea or background about it. What's on Microsoft's website is too technical for me. Please give me a more simple idea on what it is all about. :) Thanks in advance! ---Intern Here!"

To everyone:
Sorry for asking a question which is too broad. My account is currently unable to ask questions. 
Now, I have better knowledge in Coded UI, thanks to Google. I humbly admit my mistakes. Lesson learned: Google first. Thanks guys.

Comment: [Verifying Code by Using UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx): "Automated tests that drive your application through its user interface (UI) are known as coded UI tests (CUITs). These tests include functional testing of the UI controls. They let you verify that the whole application, including its user interface, is functioning correctly. Coded UI Tests are particularly useful where there is validation or other logic in the user interface, for example in a web page. They are also frequently used to automate an existing manual test."

Comment: @user2864740 You should have posted that in an answer, I'd've given you an upvote.

Comment: Go back to your team leader and tell them you don't understand. To avoid any unpleasantness don't point out that they obviously failed to check whether you did....

Comment: A very quick search of Google with "Coded UI" turned up [Verifying Code by Using UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) as the very first result. One of the very first things you should learn to do as an intern is basic research using Google or Bing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coded UI is part of the testing (quality assurance) aspect of Microsoft's software development life-cycle strategy. Coded UI tests are typically created and used by quality assurance folks to verify that code meets the business' requirements. Sometimes they share these tests with developers so developers can better repeat and understand the bugs the tests locate.

Coded UI tests themselves are basically a way of creating an automated test that tests user interface functionality. So for example, you could record navigating to a certain page in the company's application, login and then go to some page where a bug can be be made to happen. Then you could play back that actual 'recording' as many times as you want to see if the bug was fixed. There some other tools that automate stuff like this such as watir. Watir is not a test though to be clear. Just a way of automating browser strokes (and recording them).

Lastly, your team lead says code rather than record. When recording a UI test you actually do it as described above. You click record, go through the steps and then when done click stop. You can also create an automated UI test (also known as Coded UI test) using just code. You can ALSO record a coded UI test I believe and then edit it in code mode.

FORGOT to mention: You can add assertions as a part of your test (much like other forms of code testing). This means you could say that the profile should not allow a box to contain a certain value under certain conditions and the test should fail if this is allowed when the test is run.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate it! It's clearer to me now. :)

Comment: You'll need either Microsoft Test Center or depending on the version of visual studio (and tfs) either Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate to utilize them.

Comment: I currently have VS2012 Ultimate installed on my PC. Thanks again, Mike. :)

Comment: Then you are golden. They lowered the bar for which version when they went from 2010 to 12 (and now 13).